# why does UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) return true when using the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

why does `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)` return true when using the simulator?

This causes the simulator to crash when trying to access the camera.

Comment: Because simulator does not have a camera

Comment: It returns false for me. Post details about your setup.

Comment: im using iPhone 14 pro simulator, Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.4 sdk - always seems to return true - not sure why that would happen?

Comment: (lldb) po UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
true

Comment: I created a new iOS project with Xcode 14.3. I simply added `print("Has camera: \(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera))")` to the `viewDidLoad` of `ViewController`. When run on an iPhone 14 Pro iOS 16.4 simulator it prints "Has camera: false".

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ftMY7lS.jpg

Comment: @Halpo You should put that in your question. Very strange. Update your question with all of the software and hardware versions involved. Better to be in the question than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has changed with recent releases.

With Xcode 14.3.1 running the iOS 16.4 Simulator on my M2 MacBook Air, `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)` returns true. When I present `UIImagePickerController` with `sourceType = .camera`, it appears but the viewfinder only shows black. Tapping the shutter and flip camera buttons doesn't do anything. Tapping Cancel dismisses it.

Whether or not this is intentional behavior or a bug only Apple could say. :)

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Comment: My Intel Mac returns false. So maybe it's only on Apple Silicon Macs that it returns true.